# excel save and download

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, download

I'm trying to save an excel file from code and download it to the user.

the code of creating the file:

```
  Excel.Application ExcelObj = new Excel1.Application();
  Excel.Workbook wb = ExcelObj.Workbooks.Add();
  Excel.Worksheet wsh = wb.ActiveSheet;
  wsh.Cells[1, 1] =".....";
  //fill data in the file
  string errorsFileName = "Error.xls";
  string url = @"..." + errorsFileName;
  wb.SaveAs(url);
  wb.Close();
```

After the creation I can open the file from his location. **It was saved well.**

The next step is to download the file to the user, I do it with this code (that works for me in different cases!):

```
 System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
 response.ClearContent();
 response.Clear();
 //response.ContentType = "text/plain";
 response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
 response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default;
 response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetPreamble());
 response.Charset = "";
 response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName + ";");
 response.TransmitFile(url);
 response.Flush();
```

The download done , but **the file that was downloaded contains Gibberish**...

What can causes it?

Comment: Does the file contains characters of more than one language?

Comment: yes.. english and utf8 characters. what can I do to solve it?

Comment: Everything is Gibberish or just the utf8 characters? Try to set the keyboard language to a different language via Control Panel -> Region and Language. Does it change something?

Comment: Try changing content encoding                  response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

Comment: user3165438- everything is Gibberish, not only utf8 characters.

Comment: gmd- I tried UTF8 encoding . The result is the same.

Comment: I tried to set the keyboard language- it doesn't help. 
I have another place in my project that I download file with the same code - and the file downloades well from there even if it contains two languages...